# Random password generator with custom length not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code

```
from random import choice 
k=''
ps=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","9","8","0","!","%","#","/","?"]
x=int(input("enter number"))
b=choice(ps)
while len(ps) < x:
    print(b)
    k=k+b
print(b)
```

no working plz help.some more details

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Explain please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors. In the while loop you check the length of ps instead of the password. You generate a random letter only once. You also print the random letter once.

```
from random import choice 
k=''
ps=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","9","8","0","!","%","#","/","?"]
x=int(input("enter number"))

while len(k) < x:
    b=choice(ps)
    k+=b
print(k)
```

Comment: i want it all to print in a line

Comment: Don't print in the loop then.

Answer (score 0):

You can add up the generated letters into a string and print at end:

```
from random import choice 
pwd=''
ps=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","9","8","0","!","%","#","/","?"]
x=int(input("enter number"))

while len(pwd) < x:
    b=choice(ps)
    pwd += b
print(pwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest you to store all the values in a big list instead you can store them into a string like this

```
ps = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
```

and its even better to store all the alphabate and numbers separately so the script can choose randomly what to choose next
much simpler code -

```
import random

password = ""

char_string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
number_string = "1234567890"

length = 8

for i in range(length):
    char = char_string[random.randint(0, 25)]
    number = number_string[random.randint(0, 9)]
    choosen = random.choice([char, number])
    password += choosen

print(password)
```

there are much better code than this but it's efficient for you.

Answer (score -1):

```py
from secrets import choice
Result = ''
KeyList = [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
    "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4",
    "5", "6", "7", "9", "8", "0", "!", "%", "#", "/", "?"
]
Number = int(input("enter number"))
while len(Result) < Number:
    Char = choice(KeyList)
    Result += Char
print(Result)
```

DO NOT USE random MODULE FOR PASSWORD GENERATOR!
random module makes pseudorandom values. Instead, use secrets library.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

PS + Please copy&paste the error message you faced.